# How should a nested loop statement to create vertical lines in a for loop statement that creates histograms work?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, histogram, nested-loops

I am trying to use a for loop to create histograms for each fields in a dataframe. The dataframe here is labeled as 'df4'.

There are 3 fields/columns.

Then I want to create vertical lines using quantiles for each of the columns as defined in the following series: p, exp, eng.

My code below only successfully creates the vertical lines on the last field/column or histogram.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df4 = pd.read_csv("xyz.csv", index_col = "abc_id" ) 
# dataframe

# x coordinates for the lines
p = df4['abc'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95])
exp = df4['efg'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95])
eng = df4['xyz'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95])

# colors for the lines
colors = ['r','k','b','g','y']

bins = [0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df4.columns), figsize=(10, 25))
for n, col in enumerate(df4.columns):
    if (n==0):
        for xc,c in zip(exp,colors):
            plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c)
    if (n==1):
        for xc,c in zip(eng,colors):
            plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c) 
    if (n==2):
        for xc,c in zip(p,colors):
            plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c) 
    df[col].hist(ax=axs[n],bins=50)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of `plt.axvline` try `axs[n].axvline`

Comment: @JohanC - Thank you! That worked!